# Cannot find namespaces

Tags: angular, adal, adal.js

I am using ADAL in my Angular 2 App for authentication

Getting the below error while compiling.

```
ERROR in C:/abc/src/app/services/adal.service.ts (5,26): Cannot find namespace 'adal'.

ERROR in C:/abc/src/app/services/adal.service.ts (5,61): Cannot find name 'AuthenticationContext'.

ERROR in C:/abc/src/app/services/adal.service.ts (10,22): Cannot find namespace 'adal'.
webpack: Failed to compile.


adal.service.ts
----------------------------
import {ConfigService} from './config.service';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import 'expose-loader?AuthenticationContext!../../../node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js'; 
let createAuthContextFn: adal.AuthenticationContextStatic = AuthenticationContext; 

@Injectable()
export class AdalService {

    private context: adal.AuthenticationContext;
```

Am i missing any imports ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this issue by adding the below code in .angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": [
        "../node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js"
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need TypeScript definitions. Try installing with `npm install --save-dev @types/adal` in your project's root directory.

Another possible solution:

```
import * as adal from 'expose-loader?AuthenticationContext!../../../node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js'
```

or

```
import {ConfigService} from './config.service';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import { adal, AuthenticationContext, AuthenticationContextStatic } from 'expose-loader?AuthenticationContext!../../../node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js'; 
let createAuthContextFn: AuthenticationContextStatic = AuthenticationContext; 

@Injectable()
export class AdalService {
    private context: AuthenticationContext;
}
```

Comment: Now i am getting only one error.ERROR in C:/abc/src/app/services/adal.service.ts (5,61): Cannot find name 'AuthenticationContext'.

Comment: For me worked: import { adal, AuthenticationContext } from 'expose-loader?AuthenticationContext!../../../node_modules/adal-angular/lib/adal.js';